# Отправка почты посредством PHP. Header-ы

Tags: php, email

Когда я использую в качестве заголовка для mail() как строку так и массив, т.е. так:

```
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
           'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

...и так соотвественно:

```
$headers = array(
    'From' => 'webmaster@example.com',
    'Reply-To' => 'webmaster@example.com',
    'X-Mailer' => 'PHP/' . phpversion()
);
```

...то почта отправляется.

Только вот когда я пытаюсь сделать из массива строку посредством $headers = implode("\r\n", $headers); и передать уже ее в качествеа аргумента mail(), то ничего не работает и письма не приходят. Хотелось бы знать, что я делаю не так. Версия PHP 7.4.3...

Comment: После `implode()`, сделайте `var_dump()` ваших `$headers` и думаю что вопрос "что не так" отпадет сам собой.

Comment: `implode()` объединяет значения, а ключи не трогает. А в строке они требуются. Вот и получается ошибка. А так да, `print_r()` или `var_dump()` помогут понять.